# DC-DC regulator power inductor alternatives

Tags: dc-dc-converter, inductor, coil

I am using Texas Instruments Webench power designer to create Dc-DC regulator circuit. Input should be 5-12 V and output should be 5 V 3 A. I am trying to look for cheapest design. Most of generated designs contain power inductor with 2 coils, but I can't find inductor with specific inductance and two coils anywhere to buy. Would it be wrong to use single coil inductor ? What are the difference between two coils inductors and single coil? Or in this design "two coil inductor" is just a transformer being used as inductor? I will add the generated design bellow:
[image]

Comment: That's called a transformer. If it is necessary or overkill for the currents you need, I don't know - 3A from a 5V rail is a slightly unusual requirement. Some power guru better answer this.

Comment: 3 A is just to be on a safe side. Peak current would be above 1 A

Comment: What I can tell you is that I have very poor experience of using TPS series "simple switchers". We designed in very similar parts doing everything by the book and boom: lots of EMC problems. We then switched to an equivalent part from AD while keeping the design otherwise more or less the same. And all EMC problems disappeared. I guess "simple switcher" means "simply needs to be switched out for a better part". (I have been using them simple switchers since generation 1 when they were still called National, so hopefully I know what I'm talking about.)

Comment: 1A at 5V is very reasonable without a transformer. 3A is a bit harder, but still achievable. Do you really need to be able to output 5V if your input is 5V? Or are you ok with some dropout (5V -> 4.5V, or 6V -> 5V)?

Comment: @Lundin I don't have any problems with most TPS series parts, and emissions is largely a layout issue, unless there's something more part-specific (susceptibility?) you had a problem with. The 4021x specifically however, are **on my blacklist** because the control is designed to fault out as a "normal" part of operation. At least as near as I can tell. Effect being, current limiting or startup/fault behavior is *impossible* to implement smoothly; at best, an over-large C_SS gives crude (voltage-mode) startup *only*, so that nuisance trips on load step are still a problem.

Comment: I would strongly encourage LM3481 instead, or even ye olde UC3843 if the input voltage is on the higher side and you don't need super high efficiency.

Comment: @TimWilliams We didn't really have any problems with the older parts in this series either and even took some through MIL EMC testing. Specifically I'm talking about TPS560430 here, which is now on my blacklist. Because as I wrote, we did the layout by the book and yet it started to spew noise affecting nearby RF parts. Keeping the layout mostly the same but picking a part from AD/LT solved the problem. I'm literally dealing with this problem even as I write this, we have the TPS560 parts in a pre-series batch in production, but can't use them because they are crap.

Comment: Additionally, TI technical support is non-existent. LT always had excellent support.

Comment: @Lundin I second that.

Comment: Hm, fast synch part? Is that shoot-through, or, more likely for TI, dead time causing step recovery? There was an LMxxxx buck part years ago that had a similar phenomenon, resulting in ~ns rising edge and trouble all over a multilayer RF/fast ADC board. The older (TPS54xxx?) parts with outboard diode are slower, and immune to such hard-switching behavior (using schottky that is), though I haven't tested them to quite such frequencies or levels myself.

Answer (score 1):

> What are the difference between two coils inductors and single coil? Or in this design "two coil inductor" is just a transformer being used as inductor?

The design shown in your question is a non-isolated flyback converter built with a boost converter controller. And the magnetic component (`L1` if I read correctly) is a transformer but it'll be used as a coupled inductor in a flyback regulator.

> Input should be 5-12 V and output should be 5 V 3 A.

> 3 A is just to be on a safe side. Peak current would be above 1 A

For your needs, I don't see the point of going for a flyback regulator. If your requirement was something like "12-36V input, 24V output" i.e. output was "within" the input range then flyback would be an option.

> Would it be wrong to use single coil inductor ?

I don't know if you have stricter and more detailed requirements such as dynamic response, peak-to-peak ripple, EMI/EMC etc. but you could go for a buck regulator design instead which employs a single inductor (possible EMI filter is ignored) and possibly with an internal MOSFET. For 10-15W power levels there are lots of buck regulator ICs with internal MOSFETs which allow you to save space and cost. [MP2467](https://www.monolithicpower.com/en/documentview/productdocument/index/version/2/document_type/Datasheet/lang/en/sku/MP2467/document_id/263/) is one of them. Please note that this is not a blind suggestion or a specific product recommendation. Take this as an example and try to find a suitable one for your needs/requirements, using well-known retailers such as Digikey and Mouser.

Answer (score 0):

Some kind of buck-boost is required, due to the overlapping input and output voltage range.  SEPIC is a good choice here.

Yes, SEPIC can be done with single inductors.  You incur "double" the magnetizing current, and full input ripple, so it's less efficient per component size/cost.  Note the inductors act in parallel, so the total inductance is half the individual components' inductance.

Dual inductors are fairly common, in western markets at least, from all major name brands and distributors.  We can't exactly help you of course without knowing where your market is, but such is discouraged anyway (from the FAQ, "*Questions seeking recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them are off-topic as they are rarely useful to others and quickly obsolete*").  The number of parameters, and methods of sorting, at various distributors, can be confusing, or intimidating, and I would suggest (and encourage) getting accustomed to it; shopping is inevitable to the engineer.

A note on terminology: these components are better called "coupled inductors": intended to store energy per cycle, in contrast to a transformer which is intended to transform power instantaneously (cycling irrelevant) while storing a minimum of energy (low leakage, high magnetizing inductance).  Both are subsets of *non-ideal transformers*, where primary and secondary magnetizing inductance, and coupling factor or leakage inductance, are parameters.  Mind, different definitions are used in commerce; this is only a functional definition.

There is another option, the four-transistor buck-boost or "flying inductor" converter.  These are likely a more expensive option, being either more specialized ICs or modules, or requiring more parts.  But they are available, and use only a single inductor period.  Efficiency can be a concern, due to the two inverter stages.